# SQL Server & Active Directory

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, active-directory, ldap, sql-server-2016

What’s the best practice for integrating SQL Server with Active Directory (AD)?

NB. I’m using SQL Server 2016

Crux of the issue: I'm using SSRS 2016 and have several reports that need to be filtered based on the user accessing the reports. Originally I created a table of users that would need to access the reports. Then in the report builder I passed the `UserID` as a parameter within the query so that the resulting dataset would be limited to the data the user needed to see.

The problem this created is that the User table would have to be maintained, and Active Directories are dynamic. Now that I have some time to develop a better option, I’d like to link the LDAP data with SQL Server.

I’m wondering what the best practice for doing this is.

One way I pursued this was through an SSIS package ADO.Net connection. Then convert the data. Then load it into a table. Then schedule a job to run the package however often I needed it. This was problematic because for whatever reason I couldn’t get the data conversion process to work.

The second way I’ve been approaching this is to create a linked server instance for the AD. My research has indicated that I’ll need to create a function that overcomes the string limitation of the xp_sprintf Function. Then leverage temp tables and loop through LDAP data to get around the 1000 record limitation from the AD. I've been able to accomplish all this.

At this point though, there appears to be some other issues.

1. This ultimately increases the code necessary in the views for my reports which may make it harder for other database users to update if & when the time comes. To the point that I'd need to abandon the views and create stored procedures for the reports to pull from.
2. This also increases transaction counts beyond the SQL Server to include LDAP every time a user accesses a report.

So to resolve that I could wrap the original query of the LDAP data to create a table and then create a job to run that stored procedure every so often.

Either option solves the problem of maintaining the users table which is good, but it isn't perfect because AD changes can take place at any time.

Which option is better here?

If the SSIS package is the better route, I’m curious as to why that is the better route.  I’m not opposed to going back and figuring out what it is I’m missing on the SSIS package to make it work.

Are there additional options I should consider if I want to get the most up-to-date Active Directory listing?

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few years back. I ended up creating a linked Server from MSSQL to LDAP/AD then ran a job on a schedule that populated a table of users and their respective groups plus a few other things like a list of subordinates and their manager. This proved very useful for reports and other applications at the time. I did look at other options but this was the simplest/cleanest I could find.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks.

Comment: I used the same technique @AlanSchofield did and it has been running smoothly so far.